# Javascript: Determining what event causes an action

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-slides

In Google slides we interact with the document using `div` elements that are pretending to be buttons.

```
<div role="button" id=".." ..>...</div>
```

For example, we `click` on the present button using the mouse in the top right hand side of the page then the presentation begins (slide goes full screen etc...).

[image]

However, when firing a `click` event (with either javascript or jquery), the `click` is detected but the presentation is not started. So this action isn't initiated when `click` event is fired *(note, it is not the `mouseup` / `mousedown` events either)*.

How can I determine what event is actually causing the presentation to start?

Comment: Depends, how are you testing that click is fired?

Comment: In a probably non robust way :) I added `$("body").on("click", selector, function(){ console.log("clicked") })` into the page

Comment: So, you added that then clicked the button and did not see anything logged?

Comment: No, I add it and the event is logged. If I "click" the button with the mouse I receive the log message and the presentation starts. If I "click" the button using `$(selector).trigger("click")` then I receive the log message, but the presentation does not start

Comment: Ah, and I assume you tried mousedown/mouseup?

Comment: I hadn't, but I have tried it now and I confirm that it does not work either

Comment: somewhat tedious, but if you inspect the element with dev tools, on the right there is an Event Listeners tab, where you can see all the events attached to a node and by what scripts.  You could then go look at said scripts to see how each event is attached.